# Prince FAMD unable to transform data (shapes not aligned:(dim 1) != (dim 0))

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I'm using prince to perform Factor Analysis of Mixed Data (FAMD). During training everything goes as planned, but when I try to transform new data, I get an error (shapes not aligned:(dim 1) != (dim 0)).

I've seen people claiming to have this problem before and they claim the problem is that they're trying to transform data from a test set, but I tried different approaches and I still get this error. Let me describe my situation:

- My dataset has some 500k rows and some 20 columns.
- Originally, I separated the dataset into a train(80%) and test(20%) and everything worked fine
- The problem appears when I try to transform a small subset of the data

  - When I try transforming less than 100 rows, I get the aforementioned error
  - Between 100 and 2000 rows, there's no error, but the output is all nan
  - Over 2000 rows it works properly

Does anyone know how to fix this? I think it may be some issue with matrix rank, but right now I'm clueless

Here's the error message

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 7 famd.transform(c)
>
> \site-packages\prince\mfa.py in
> transform(self, X)
> 135     def transform(self, X):
> 136         """Returns the row principal coordinates of a dataset."""
> --> 137         return self.row_coordinates(X)
> 138
> 139     def _row_coordinates_from_global(self, X_global):
>
> \site-packages\prince\mfa.py in
> row_coordinates(self, X)
> 152         X = self._prepare_input(X)
> 153
> --> 154         return self._row_coordinates_from_global(self._build_X_global(X))
> 155
> 156     def row_contributions(self, X):
>
> \site-packages\prince\mfa.py in
> _row_coordinates_from_global(self, X_global)
> 139     def _row_coordinates_from_global(self, X_global):
> 140         """Returns the row principal coordinates."""
> --> 141         return len(X_global) ** 0.5 * super().row_coordinates(X_global)
> 142
> 143     def row_coordinates(self, X):
>
> \site-packages\prince\pca.py in
> row_coordinates(self, X)
> 136             X = self.scaler_.transform(X)
> 137
> --> 138         return pd.DataFrame(data=X.dot(self.V_.T), index=index, dtype=np.float64)
> 139
> 140     def row_standard_coordinates(self, X):
>
> ValueError: shapes (100,41) and (43,10) not aligned: 41 (dim 1) != 43
> (dim 0)